# iOS8 Spritekit lag

Tags: ios8, sprite-kit

I programmed a game with Spritekit for iOS7. After I updated my iPhone to iOS8, my game is lagging at some Points:

1.: Picture B is placed in zPosition behind Picture A (Both pictures are loaded at the start of the scene.) When I reach the score "50", picture A should fade out and picture B should get visible. (I used SKAction to fade out)
This worked absolutely fine with iOS7. In iOS8 there is a little lag for about half a second. The framerate stays on 60fps.

2.: When you reach for example score "50" a sprite with an image should move from the top to the middle. This sprite is also loaded at the start of the scene and as long as the score is below 50, outside of the visible screen.
But here the it lags for around half a second,too.

Comment: are you using enumerateChildNodesWithName any where in your code

Answer (score 0):

This is an iOS 8 issue. I had the same exact problem with my game. It was working perfectly in iOS7 and as soon as I updated to iOS8, it was completely laggy. My problem was that the physics world.speed variable does not work the same way in iOS 8 as it did in iOS7. If you have changed that variable, make sure it is or very close to 1 (the default value).